# Embedding link into SGV inside .attr

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The following is a part of the javascript of an SVG I am working on,

```
  var clockCenter = this.s.circle(200, 200, 5);
  clockCenter.attr({
    fill: "#DDD",
    stroke: "transparent",
    strokeWidth: 30
  });
```

And I want to embed a code inside this attribute to direct the user to `http://example.com` by clicking the SVG image. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just want to be able to click on a circle in your svg and navigate to a page?

You can do it simply like this:

(Add an `onclick` parameter and tell it to call the `clickLink` event - note you could also use a `querySelector(All)` to select the svg element(s) and then use `addEventListener`)

```js
function clickLink(elem){
  // Note you can also get the 'data-href' attribute like this:
  // elem.dataset.href;
  // or you can use getAttribute as below:
  window.location.href = elem.getAttribute('data-href');
  
  // OR open in new tab:
  // window.open(elem.getAttribute('data-href'), '_blank');  
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="100 100 300 300">

  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="5"  
    onclick="clickLink(this)"
    data-href="https://www.example.com"
    fill="#DDD"
    stroke="transparent"
    strokeWidth="30" />  

</svg>
```